# Re-run part of an Airflow Subdag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a daily Dag that contains a subdag. The subdag has five tasks, T1 through T5, that must run in order (e.g. T1 >> T2 >> T3 >> T4 >> T5)

The dag successfully runs for a few days but then I discover a bug with T4. I fix the bug and want to re-run just T4 and T5 for all previous days. It's important to NOT re-run T1-T3 because these steps take a lot longer than T4-T5.

What I've tried that has failed:

1. Select T4, Clear downstream+recursive - Nothing happens. The Dag tree view shows the subdag as "success" even though T4 and T5 within it are cleared.
2. Select T4, clear downstream+recursive, select subdag, clear just that task - This will re-run the entire subdag (T1-T5) even though T1-T3 were marked as success
3. Select T4, clear downstream+recursive, select subdag, click run - Same as #2. Re-runs entire subdag.
4. Select T4, clear downstream+recursive, manually set the subdag to "running" state.  Nothing happens. The tree view shows the subdag in the "running" state but no tasks actually get run.

This seems to only be a problem when trying to re-run part of a subdag. If I have a bunch of tasks in a regular dag, normally selecting a task in the middle and selecting clear downstream+recursive will re-run the dag from that point.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think #2 should have done what you wanted. What version of Airflow are you running? [AIRFLOW-1124](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1124) should've fixed the issue of every task getting rescheduled in a backfill and is applied to versions 1.8.1+.

Comment: v1.8.0 - I'm planning to upgrade Airflow to 1.9 soon so maybe it will get solved by that. Thanks for the response.

Comment: seems 1.9 doesn't work too.

Comment: Have you tried your 4th approach but with setting the parent DAG run(s) to running state?  I think that should make the SubDAG tasks that have been cleared re-run without re-running the completed ones.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Yes, I've made sure the parent DAG is marked as running. Actually just clearing the individual tasks or subdag tasks automatically puts the parent DAG into running state. And also, I've upgraded to 1.9 and this still doesn't seem to work for me. I've just stopped using SubDags entirely in all my flows.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Have you been able to test your DAG code against the Airflow master branch to see if it works there?  If you can update your question with a MCVE of your DAG / SubDAG code, we can help troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 16):

You can restart the failed tasks inside a subDAG, this is how:

- Zoom into the subDAG, clear the status of failed tasks.
- Go back to main DAG, select the subDAG.
- Uncheck Recursive and/or Downstream.
- Clear status of subDAG.

Comment: Tested in Airflow 1.9 with a nearly identical setup and this should be the accepted answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to run a subdag successfully, hope it can helps someone:

airflow backfill  dag_name.subdag_name  -s 2018-05-31 -e 2018-05-31 --reset_dagruns